# Sqlite a database with multiple table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to handle two tables in a database.
If I created other table, do we have to use primary key id field or using different key id?
It is what I am doing.
Could you give me feedback for me?
Thanks.

```
public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
    return db.query(FRIDGE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_EXPIRED_DATE, KEY_IMAGE }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
}
// return cursor over the list of all items in freezer table
public Cursor freezer_fetchAllItems() {
    return db.query(FREEZER_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_EXPIRED_DATE, KEY_IMAGE }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand your question at all! Do you want to create a third table besides FRIDGE_TABLE and FREEZER_TABLE?

You might want to brush up on some SQL basics. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp is a good starting point.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla please avoid w3schools - w3fools.com | as for SQL basic, try this one as an alternative: http://www.sqltutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, android requires all primary keys to be _id.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/